# VimTex is nonstop compiling if gnuplottex is used

Tags: neovim, plugin-vimtex, lazyvim

I am using VimTex to write LaTex. I am trying to use **gnuplottex** in my documents, but get the problem that VimTex won't stop compiling the tex file. I am guessing that some gnuplot related files are changed, which triggers the compilation (I am using the automatic compilation). How could I fix the behaviour so that it does only compile e.g. if the **.tex** or the **.bib** file is changed?

I use neovim with the following setting:

`vim.g.vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {options = { "-pdf", "-shell-escape"},}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've specified the latexmk options in a way that is not according to the documentation and that is likely the cause of your problem. See `:help vimtex_compiler_latexmk`, which states:

```
  Default value:

    let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
        \ …
        \ 'options' : [
        \   '-verbose',
        \   '-file-line-error',
        \   '-synctex=1',
        \   '-interaction=nonstopmode',
        \ ],
        \}
  …
  options
    This is a list of options that are passed to `latexmk`. The default
    options should work well for most people.

    Note: Options like `-pdf` or `-lualatex` should NOT be added to this list.
          These are options used to specify the LaTeX processor/engine, see
          instead |g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk_engines|.
```

You probably didn't read the last note. Also, you need to keep the default options as well. Thus, you probably want this:

```lua
vim.g.vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
  options = {
    "-shell-escape",
    "-verbose",
    "-file-line-error",
    "-synctex=1",
    "-interaction=nonstopmode",
  },
}
```

I strongly advice all users to actually read the docs. I don't mean to read *all* of it, but read the docs for the options you are using. And read the introduction. I've taken a lot of care into making the documentation useful as *the* reference for VimTeX. ;)

---

Also: This is a question that is generally better to ask at the VimTeX issue tracker (https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/). I suggest that you open an issue in the issue tracker if you have further questions related to VimTeX.